# Do Parasaurolophus have hands with fingers to grab?

Tags: evolution, extinction, climate-change, reptile, global-warming

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasaurolophus#mediaviewer/File:Parasaurolophus_cyrtocristatus.jpg

I cannot tell if the hands have fingers strung together to form a hove, or fingers to grab. I have seen so many pictures of Parasaurolophus standing up, suggesting possible other functions of the arms and hands. I think their arms are long enough to reach their mouth. Ironically, I have yet to find any literature talking about their hands, but lots of literature talking about their resonating chamber. Do Parasaurolophus have hands with fingers to grab?

[image]